# Why is it so difficult to set the location of Splitter?

Tags: vb.net

The content of the codes given below;
3 panels and 2 Splitter are required. However, the 2nd splitter (Green) must be located between the gray and brown panel. But not in the right place. Are there any suggestions?
Thanks.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Show()

        Dim tmpSplitter As Splitter
        Dim tmpPanel As Panel
        Dim MainPanel As Panel

        ' This is main panel
        '
        MainPanel = New Panel
        With MainPanel
            .Name = "MainPanel"
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .BackColor = Color.LightGray
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            .Visible = True
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(MainPanel)

        ' 1: First Top Panel and Splitter 
        '
        tmpPanel = New Panel
        With tmpPanel
            .Name = "Panel1"
            .Dock = DockStyle.Top
            .BackColor = Color.Red
            .Visible = True
        End With

        tmpSplitter = New Splitter
        With tmpSplitter
            .Name = "Split1"
            .Dock = DockStyle.Top
            .BackColor = Color.Blue
            .Cursor = Cursors.HSplit
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(tmpSplitter)
        Me.Controls.Add(tmpPanel)


        ' 2: Second Panel added to the left side of the main panel
        '
        MainPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Right
        MainPanel.Size = New Size(MainPanel.Width * 0.5, MainPanel.Height)

        Dim btn As New Button
        btn.Size = New Size(10, 50)
        btn.Location = New Point(MainPanel.Location.X - btn.Width, MainPanel.Location.Y)
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)


        tmpPanel = New Panel
        With tmpPanel
            .Size = New Size(10, MainPanel.Height)
            .Location = New Point(MainPanel.Location.X - .Width - 5, MainPanel.Location.Y)
            .Name = "Panel2"
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .BackColor = Color.Brown
        End With

        ' THIS SPLITTER IS NOT IN THE RIGHT PLACE. Must be between brown and gray panel
        '
        tmpSplitter = New Splitter
        With tmpSplitter
            .Size = New Size(5, MainPanel.Height)
            .Location = New Point(MainPanel.Location.X - .Width, MainPanel.Location.Y)
            .Name = "Split2"
            .Dock = DockStyle.Right
            .BackColor = Color.Green
            .Cursor = Cursors.VSplit
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(tmpSplitter)
        Me.Controls.Add(tmpPanel)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Splitter was a pretty awkward .NET 1.0 control.  Replaced in .NET 2.0 by SplitContainer, realistically only the class you can get help with here.  Not likely you'll need any.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but the splitcontainer has 2 panels. more panels need to add new ones into splitcontainer. My problem is that the splitter can be manually added to the design stage, but I couldn't add the code to the desired location.

Comment: `.Dock` and `.Location` can't work together. Whenever you set the `Dock` property of a control to something other than `None`, that overrides whatever value used for the `Location` property. You need to understand [how docking works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-controls-on-windows-forms). Also, you may consider (when appropriate) using the [`Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-controls-on-windows-forms) property instead.

Answer (score 0):

a little more research and try to solve the solution

```
Me.Controls.SetChildIndex (tmpSplitter, 0)
```

is enough to write on the last line. Thank you for your contributions.